# Modifications for a matplotlib example is not working correctly

Tags: python, class, matplotlib

Iam trying to make a matplotlib note draggable using an example from the documents of matplotlib. This is the example called ["Draggable rectangle exercise"](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html?highlight=drag)

So, i created a class that draws a `matplotlib` figure and have a method called `addNote` where my problem is. Here, is where i try to call the `DraggableNote`class like this:

```
class MatplotFigure(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
      self.text_list =[]
      self.notes_list = []
      #A lot of stuff in here for creating the figure

    def addNote(self, text):    #"text" is a variable that i get from another class
      self.text_list.append(text)

      notes = self.axes.annotate(text, xy=(0.2, 0.2))
      dr = DraggableNote(notes)

      for note in notes_list:
         dr.connect()

      self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()


class DraggableNote:
def __init__(self, notes):
    self.rect = notes
    self.press = None

def connect(self):
    'connect to all the events we need'
    self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_press_event', self.on_press)
    self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_release_event', self.on_release)
    self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    print "se conecto"

def on_press(self, event):
    'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
    if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return

    contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
    if not contains: return
    print 'event contains', self.rect.xy
    x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
    self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata

    print "conectado a on_press"

def on_motion(self, event):
    'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
    if self.press is None: return
    if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
    x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
    dx = event.xdata - xpress
    dy = event.ydata - ypress
    print 'x0=%f, xpress=%f, event.xdata=%f, dx=%f, x0+dx=%f'%(x0, xpress, event.xdata, dx, x0+dx)
    self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
    self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

    self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    print "se conecto a on_motion"

def on_release(self, event):
    'on release we reset the press data'
    self.press = None
    self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    print "se conecto a on_release"

def disconnect(self):
    'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
    self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
    self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
    self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

    print "se conecto a disconnect"
```

### ------------EDIT-------------

I change the original code that you can see above, because i solved the problem that i had before. So, i did no notice the mistake of writing the coordinates in the line:

`notes = self.axes.annotate(text, xy=(0.2, 0.2))`

because every time that i click in the stickynote that i create in the figure, it starts from the coordinates given in that line, that is `x = 0.2` and `y = 0.2`.

The problem seems to be in the `on_press` method, in line:

`x0, y0 = self.rect.xy`

How can i refresh those coordinates every time that i move the stickynote?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Take a look at the for loop inside the `addNode` method. You are calling the `connect` over the same object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what i want, to be calling the object so it moves every time that i click on it. Or do you refer to another issue?